# What does the apostrophe on the $x$ mean for this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find $f^{-1}(x)$, the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x'}$. I know that to find the inverse we just swap the positions of $x$ and $y$ of the original function and the solve for $x$.

After swapping, $x'\to y'$

this is a pre-calculus question so I'm assuming that it doesn't mean the derivative.  What does the apostrophe mean?

Equation is found from a pre-calculus worksheet. Instructor is unavailable and above instructions and function is all that's been given.

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to know without knowing more about the context of where you found this equation.

Comment: equation is found from a pre-calculus worksheet.  Instructor is unavailable and above instructions and function is all that's been given.

Comment: could the "apostrophe" be a typo. or a smudge?

Comment: Are your confident there _is_ a tick there? Could it be a typesetting/print error, or, if the sheet is handwritten, a poorly drawn exponent?

Comment: very sure there is a tick

Comment: I can’t think of any obvious explanation without more contact either. You could consider adding a photo of the worksheet.

Comment: In the picture, the tick appears to be a comma in the sentence, as in "Given [this function], determine ...".

Comment: I think that's the answer, @Blue

Answer (score 3):

Converting a comment to an answer:

In the picture, the tick appears to be a comma in the sentence, as in "Given [this function], determine ...".